# Changing Labels on Viss_miss

Tags: r, naniar

I'm trying to create a missingness diagram of my data. 
I've ran the following code:

```
library(visdat)
library(naniar)

vis_miss(data, sort_miss = TRUE, show_perc = TRUE)
```

However, the labels are `employment.factor` or a variation instead of `Employment`. How do I change this label?

Also, all of my variables in the dataset are included here. How do I select which certain variables are included in the missingness diagram?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data please?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing the variable names after plotted, can you change the variable names to a new subset from the actual data set, THEN plot?
Using the dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)
data_subset <- select(data, A, B, C)
vis_miss(data_subset)
```

sort_miss=TRUE arranges the variables by most missingness on the x-axis which you have included
vis_miss returns a ggplot object so it is possible to change labels apparently. This github project seems to have provided an example using vis_miss and R's airquality data set: https://github.com/ropensci/visdat/blob/master/R/vis-miss.R

You can get the order of columns with highest missingness:

```
na_sort <- order(colSums(is.na(data)), decreasing = TRUE)
```

Then get the names of those columns:

```
col_order_index <- names(data)[na_sort]
```

Gather the variables together for plotting (column of the row number, then variable, then contents of that variable)

```
dat_pre_vis <- as.data.frame(data.na[row_order_index , ])
```

Have you tried pulling up the help documentation for ?naniar which lists all of its available functions included in the package? There is some explanation about using naniar here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/naniar/vignettes/naniar-visualisation.html